# How to Sync MySQL database and Word Press Database

Tags: sync, mysql, database, wordpress

I have two projects one is WordPress project and the other one is a mobile app with Java backend  + MySql database. The content management is handled from the web with WordPress project. However, I need to sync these two databases. WordPress to MySql database or MySql to WordPress. Any idea how can I manage this?

Comment: What Database is WordPress using

Comment: I think it is using MySQL. However, the problem is in the contents. In wp contents have some sort of html tags..